# python shell in Sublime text 3

Tags: python, shell, sublimetext3

I have recently downloaded Sublime Text 3 and since it does not have a Python shell, I have downloaded SublimeREPL, but every time I run the code by `SublimeREPL >>> Python >>> Python - Run current file` I get `***Repl Closed***` text after the output, which prevents me from interacting with the shell. Is there any way around this?

Comment: If you are using Windows, you can simply use the Command Prompt, first by entering the folder where your .py is located: cd <full/file/path>. Assuming you have one python version installed, you can then type in python filename.py . If you are on Linux, python will come preinstalled. Open the terminal, enter the directory of your file: cd <full/file/path> . The if you are using Python 3, type in python3 filename.py, if you are using Python 2, type in python filename.py . Hope it helps :)

Comment: Does your program terminate ? Or does it run a loop ?

Comment: @Flint the programs compile just fine, but in IDLE, i was capable of doing additional operations in shell after program was executed, like checking what values certain variables hold etc. But with ***repl closed*** I cannot do that

Comment: a python code can be loaded from a running program, that's why I asked if the program did terminate. In a interactive mode, with, say, a rendering thread, it's perfectly possible to interact with a running program and enter commands to modify some values on the fly. Of course that good IDLE keeps the interpreter open, since it continues to run IDLE itself.

Comment: Tried Jupyter or Ipython with %autoreload option ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well not 100% convinced by SublimeREPL, but let's get straight to the solution :

Find the Python configuration

```
~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/SublimeREPL/config/Python/Main.sublime-menu
```

add the **`-i`** flag to the python command in this section (you're also free to create a new one)

```
{"command": "repl_open",
 "caption": "Python - RUN current file",
 "id": "repl_python_run",
 "mnemonic": "R",
 "args": {
    "type": "subprocess",
    "encoding": "utf8",
```

`"cmd": ["python",` **"-i"** `,"-u", "$file_basename"],`

```
    "cwd": "$file_path",
    "syntax": "Packages/Python/Python.tmLanguage",
    "external_id": "python",
    "extend_env": {"PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8"}
```

Now the interpreter stays open upon program completion.